# Should I trim my conifer hedge with shears or an electric trimmer?

Tags: pruning, tools, hedge

Are there reasons to select hedge shears vs electric trimmers when trimming a conifer hedge? I have about 30 meters to trim, and haven't purchased either of these yet. Which option would you choose for this situation?

[image: electric trimmer]
[image: hedge shears]

Answer (score 5):

It would be easy to make 30m of hedge look like one long hedge with the electric trimmer.  It would also be easy to get carried away and trim too much with the electric model.  I would get both.  I'd rough-cut a general shape with the electric and do detail work with the hand shears.  In my experience with electric trimmers, they tend to be underpowered and dull easy, so I would buy something top-notch with plenty of power.  The hand trimmer I would get from the dollar store, but I wouldn't skimp on the electric trimmer.

Answer (score 2):

For 30m of hedge, I would buy and electric or petrol trimmer. Doing it all by hand with shears will take a long time and more skill.